# How to fix the difference in precision between double data type and uint64

Tags: matlab, modular-arithmetic, block-cipher

I'm in the process of implementing Three Fish block cipher using MATLAB. At first, I implemented the algorithm on uint8 numbers to validate my code. Every thing was OK and the decryption was successful. But when I replaced the numbers to uint64 the plain text did not retrieved correctly.
I traced the rounds results again and over again to find the reason, but I couldn't find it so far. There is difference in the first four digits between encryption and decryption, that is, along the rounds x encrypted as 9824265115183455531, but it decrypts as 9824265115183455488.

I think the reason behind this difference is in the functions AddMod64 and SubMod64 to find arithmetic modulo 2 to the power 64. but really I could not fix it so far.

I know that

```
    double(2^64) = 18446744073709552000
```

and

```
uint64(2^64) = 18446744073709551615 % z = ( x + y ) % 2^64
function z = AddMod64(x , y)
    m = uint64(2^64);
    z = double(mod(mod(double(x),m)+mod(double(y),m),m));
end
% z = (x - y ) % 2^64
function z = SubMod64(x , y)
    m = uint64(2^64);
    z = double(mod(mod(double(x),m) - mod(double(y),m),m)); 
end
```

Comment: You should not be using floating point for cryptography.

Comment: MATLAB does saturated arithmetic. If I does not use double,  then mod(uint8(255+2),256) will be 255, while the correct result must be 1

Comment: `double(2^64)` is already the wrong result, the `double` type can hold only up to `2^52-1` as an integer without rounding. Use `maxint` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`double(2^64)` is already the wrong result, the `double` type can hold only up to `2^52-1` as an integer without rounding.

Also, when you do `uint64(2^64)`, the power is computed using `double`, giving the wrong result, which you then cast to `uint64`. And because the maximum value that a `uint64` van hold is 2^64-1, that whole operation is wrong.

Use [`maxint`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intmax.html) instead:

```
m = maxint('uint64');
```

To do modulo addition in MATLAB is rather tricky, because MATLAB does saturated arithmetic with integers. You need to test for overflow before doing the computation.

```
if x > m - y
   x = y - (m - x + 1);
else
   x = x + y
end
```

Comment: intmax('uint64') = uint64(2^64) = 18446744073709551615

Comment: Before writing the code, I had computationally traced the Three Fish block cipher key scheduling and encryption by hand on uint8 numbers. 
When I wrote the code, at first, I tested for overflow before doing the modulo addition (as you mentioned). But My code (AddMod8 function, which operate on uint8) has matched the paper result more than the code you mentioned

Comment: Note that `intmax('uint64')` is 2^64-1. That your two operations return the same value is a combination of luck (the double computation is not rounded down) and saturation in the conversion to `uint64`.

Comment: Also, if your saturated addition for 8 bits gives a different result to the mod version for 8 bits then you did something wrong. For 64 bits you cannot use the mod function, doubles cannot hold a 64-but integer without loss.